# Increase c# list performance

Tags: c#, list, performance-testing

I have a C# class with 20 fields and I am looping through a List "A" (list of class objects) and adding all the values in List "A" to List "B" (list of class objects) . At any given time the maximum number of values in List "A" will not exceed 160 records.

It is taking me 25 Secs for the operation to get completed (Looping through List "A" and adding them to List "B")

I tried changing the list to `HashSet` and the performance time was reduced to 19 secs. What can I do to increase the performance significantly i.e to get it down to 2-3 seconds. Any suggestions?

```
var products = new List<ProductDto>();
using (var _userEntities = new UserEntities())
{
    UserDto user = GetUserDto(userEmail, _userEntities);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var users = _userEntities.Where(x.User.userId == user.Id);
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            if (_userEntities.Products.FirstOrDefault(y => y.userId == user.Id) != null)
            {
                var Product = new ProductDto()
                {
                    Id = user.Id.ToString(),
                    ProductId = user.Product != null ? user.ProductId : string.Empty,   
                    Name = user.Product != null ? user.Product.Name : string.Empty,
                    SalePrice = user.SalePrice == null ? string.Empty : user.SalePrice.ToString(),
                    OrderId = user.OrderID,
                    CreatedDate = user.CreatedDate,
                    HasChildItems = user.Product != null && user.Product.HasChildItems != null && user.Product.HasChildItems ? true : false,
                    OrderNumber = user.OrderNumber,

                };

                products.Add(Product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are just doing `listB.AddRange(listA);`?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why this operation should take this long.  The issue isn't the list itself, it is what you're doing with it.  Post your relevant code please.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some code.

Comment: @DavidL Added the code

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. You have a classic select n+1 query here. The issue isn't the list. It's the amount of sql queries that you are generating.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the length of the list but the number of SQL queries. If you have 160 elements you have at list 161 sql statements which seems to be very slow in your case (use a profiler to analyze). You can try to modify your linq query to join the required products with the users. I don't know your data model, but it could be something like this:

```
var users = from u in dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Product);
```

or

```
var products = from p in dbContext.Products.Include(p => p.User);
```

Eager loading instead of lazy loading.